# THREE.js Secondary camera rotated with head rotation in VR

Tags: three.js, camera, aframe

I'm using THREE.js and Aframe ( in Exokit ) together and I have a component for a "selfie camera". I have a weird issue that when i enter VR the camera rotation is taken over by the head rotation. I understand how the camera rotation works has changed in recent versions of THREE.js ( ArrayCamera ) but I assumed that only affected the main camera and not all cameras in the scene.

Below is my hacky component that works fine in 2D mode but in VR it messes up. The worst thing about it is im fine with it being linked to the head, the camera itself is a child object of the main camera anyway so it appears in front of the users face when opened and is moved with the head rotation - but its off angle when in VR like its pointing down and to the left a bit.

Here are some screenshots that hopefully demonstrate the issue:

Edit: need 10 rep to post images so here are urls instead

[2D Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Y5ge.png)

[VR Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuaK8.jpg)

Any help much appreciated!!

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('selfie-camera', {
    schema:{
        resolution:{type:'int',default:512},
        fov:{type:'int',default:100},
        aspect:{type:'number',default:1.5},
        near:{type:'number',default:0.001},
        far:{type:'number',default:1000}
    },
    init() {
        this.el.addEventListener('loaded',()=>{
            this.renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(this.data.resolution*1.5, this.data.resolution,{ antialias: true });
            this.el.getObject3D('mesh').material.map = this.renderTarget.texture;
            this.cameraContainer = new THREE.Object3D();
            this.el.object3D.add( this.cameraContainer );
            this.el.takePicture = this.takePicture.bind(this);
            this.el.setSide = this.setSide.bind(this);
            this.wider = 1.5;
            this.photoMultiplier = 2;
            this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        });
        this.testQuat = new THREE.Quaternion();
        this.el.open = this.open.bind(this);
        this.el.close = this.close.bind(this);
    },
    open(){
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( this.data.fov, this.data.aspect, this.data.near, this.data.far );
        this.cameraContainer.add(this.camera);
        new TWEEN.Tween(this.el.getAttribute('scale'))
            .to(new THREE.Vector3(1,1,1), 650)
            .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.Out).start();
    },
    close(){
        new TWEEN.Tween(this.el.getAttribute('scale'))
            .to(new THREE.Vector3(0.0000001,0.0000001,0.0000001), 200)
            .onComplete(()=>{
                this.cameraContainer.remove(this.camera);
                delete this.camera;
            })
            .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.Out).start();
    },
    tick(){
        if(this.camera){
            this.camera.getWorldQuaternion(this.testQuat);
            console.log(this.camera.quaternion);
        }
        this.el.getObject3D('mesh').material.visible = false;
        if(this.isTakingPicture) {
            this.renderTarget.setSize(this.data.resolution * this.wider * this.photoMultiplier, this.data.resolution * this.photoMultiplier);
        }
        this.el.sceneEl.renderer.render( this.el.sceneEl.object3D, this.camera, this.renderTarget );
        if(this.isTakingPicture){
            this.isTakingPicture = false;
            this.pictureResolve(this.createImageFromTexture());
            this.renderTarget.setSize(this.data.resolution * this.wider, this.data.resolution);
        }
        this.el.getObject3D('mesh').material.visible = true;
    },
    setSide(isFront){
        let _this = this;
        new TWEEN.Tween({y:this.cameraContainer.rotation.y})
            .to({y:isFront?Math.PI:0}, 350)
            .onUpdate(function(){
                _this.cameraContainer.rotation.y = this.y;
            })
            .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.Out).start();
    },
    takePicture(){
        return new Promise(resolve=>{
            this.isTakingPicture = true;
            this.pictureResolve = resolve;
        })
    },
    createImageFromTexture() {
        let width = this.data.resolution*this.wider*this.photoMultiplier,
            height = this.data.resolution*this.photoMultiplier;
        let pixels = new Uint8Array(4 * width * height);
        this.el.sceneEl.renderer.readRenderTargetPixels(this.renderTarget, 0, 0, width, height, pixels);
        pixels = this.flipPixelsVertically(pixels, width, height);
        let imageData = new ImageData(new Uint8ClampedArray(pixels), width, height);

        this.canvas.width = width;
        this.canvas.height = height;
        let context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

        context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
        return this.canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg',100);
    },
    flipPixelsVertically: function (pixels, width, height) {
        let flippedPixels = pixels.slice(0);
        for (let x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
            for (let y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
                flippedPixels[x * 4 + y * width * 4] = pixels[x * 4 + (height - y) * width * 4];
                flippedPixels[x * 4 + 1 + y * width * 4] = pixels[x * 4 + 1 + (height - y) * width * 4];
                flippedPixels[x * 4 + 2 + y * width * 4] = pixels[x * 4 + 2 + (height - y) * width * 4];
                flippedPixels[x * 4 + 3 + y * width * 4] = pixels[x * 4 + 3 + (height - y) * width * 4];
            }
        }
        return flippedPixels;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to disable VR before rendering:

```
var renderer = this.el.sceneEl.renderer;
var vrEnabled = renderer.vr.enabled;
renderer.vr.enabled = false;
renderer.render(this.el.sceneEl.object3D, this.camera, this.renderTarget);
renderer.vr.enabled = vrEnabled;
```